# UICollectionView scroll if vertical, move cell if horizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that scrolls vertically but only if I am not touching a cell or it's content.

`UICollectionView` -> `UICollectionViewCell` -> `UIView`

The UIView has a pan gesture

```
- (void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{}
```

which I use to move the `UIView` around. If the `UIView` is in the `UICollectionView` it is restricted to only horizontal movement. If I move the `UIView` out of the bounds of the `UICollectionView` then it is removed from the collection.

I want the `UICollectionView` to scroll vertically if I am moving my finger vertically, which would have to cause the touch events on the `UIView` to be ignored. But if I move horizontally the touch events will not be ignored on the `UIView`.

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Advice would be greatly appreciated.